# Could not create azure compute instances using azure devops CI pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-cli, mlops

Below is the error I am getting

ERROR: {'Azure-cli-ml Version': '1.27.0', 'Error': AuthenticationException:

Message: Could not retrieve user token. Please run 'az login'

InnerException Please run 'az login' to setup account.

ErrorResponse

{

"error": {

"code": "UserError",

"inner_error": {

"code": "Authentication"

},

"message": "Could not retrieve user token. Please run 'az login'"

}

}}

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that you didn't use an available service connection for the subscription you want to create the VM in, or you didn't use the command `az login` in the CLI script. You can choose one way from above.

Maybe you use the YAML file to define your task, then you need to set the `azureSubscription` option, it sets the service connection for you. See the description of the Azure CLI task [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).